# Divide data array in more efficient way Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have a big array of data (it can be of thousands and tens of thousands of values). This data is a results of experiments collected in one array:

```
 data = [2.204000000000000
   2.202000000000000
   2.206000000000000
   2.201000000000000
   ...
   ]
```

And I have time array `t` of the same size:

```
t = [1 2 3 ... 65 66 1 2 3 4 ... 72 73 1 2 3 ... 75]';
```

This `t` is a time when the data was collected. So `t = 1:66` - is a first experiment, and then `t` values again begins from `1` - it is data of 2 experiment and etc.
What I want to do: divide data by the specific time intervals:

```
t<=1
1<t<=4
4<t<=6
t>6
```

I go this way

```
part1 = []; part2 = []; part3 = []; part4 = [];
for ii = 1: size(data,1) 
    if (t(ii)) <=1      % collect all data corresponds to t<=1
        part1 = [part1; ii];
    elseif (t(ii) >1 &&  t(ii) <=4 )
        part2 = [part2; ii];
    elseif (t(ii) >4 &&  t(ii) <=6 )
        part3 = [part3; ii];
    else
        part4 = [part4; ii];
    end
end
data1 = data(part1);
data2 = data(part2);
data3 = data(part3);
data4 = data(part4);
```

That works perfect but it's slow because of:

1. I can't preallocate `part1 part2 part3 part4` - I don't know their sizes;
2. It use `for` loop.

Can we do it in more elegant and fast way?

---

Now I have an idea of using one cell array instead of 4 different. Now I use `part{1} part{2} ... part{4}`. So I can preallocate it as `part = cell(4,1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve your code using **logical indexing**.

I strongly encourage you to read the following references:

- Mathworks documentation page: [Find Array Elements That Meet a Condition](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html)
- Loren on the Art of MATLAB blog entry: [Logical Indexing – Multiple
  Conditions](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/)

---

The following code uses logical indexing to do what you want without any loop, and thus without the need to preallocate any arrays:

```
data1 = data(t <= 1);
data2 = data((t > 1) && (t <= 4));
data3 = data((t > 4) && (t <= 6));
data4 = data(t > 6);
```

---

Logical indexing is like a traffic light: It allows the elements of an array that have a value of `1` to continue while stopping those elements that have a value of `0`.

Matlab is very powerful in this kind of tasks.

Comment: Ahhh really, I just overthink about it :) easy solution! 
All my misunderstanding was because of I use cell arrays everywhere (replaced it with numeric arrays in question just for readability). So this `t{1,1}(1:end)` and etc. just litter my eyes and I can't see this :) Thank you!

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Thanks for taking your time to provide a simplified version of your code. Yes, as you mention, it is a little bit less obfuscated with numeric arrays than it is with cell arrays, but it works well on both. I updated my answer with more interesting links that you might find helpful. Cheers!